# Parse xml with namespace in RootElement in android sax parser

Tags: android, parsing, sax

I try parse this [rss news](http://www.postfactum.ks.ua/feed)  using android [sax parser](https://github.com/salendron/Simple-Rss2-Android).

```
final RSSItem currentMessage = new RSSItem();
    RootElement root = new RootElement("rss");
    final List<RSSItem> messages = new ArrayList<RSSItem>();
    Element channel = root.getChild("channel");
    Element item = channel.getChild(ITEM);
```

But I catch exception:

```
05-08 18:29:25.004    2820-2820/com.xmlsimplesaxparser V/SimpleRss2ParserDemo﹕ android.sax.BadXmlException: Line 1: Root element name does not match. Expected: 'rss', Got: 'http://backend.userland.com/rss2:rss'
```

When I add namespace:

`static final String NAMESPACE ="http://backend.userland.com/rss2";`:

```
 final RSSItem currentMessage = new RSSItem();
    RootElement root = new RootElement(NAMESPACE, "rss");
    final List<RSSItem> messages = new ArrayList<RSSItem>();
    Element channel = root.getChild(NAMESPACE, "channel");
    Element item = channel.getChild(NAMESPACE, ITEM);
```

I get `NullPointerException`. How to use namespace in sax parser?

Comment: Can you post your XML too?

Comment: see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/shtankoksu/1530fee34a05075f1c07)

Comment: Where did you get the NullPointerException?

Comment: `item.setEndElementListener(new EndElementListener() {
            public void end() {
                messages.add(currentMessage.copy()); //NullPointerExeption
            }
        });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected this problem: needed add namespace to all tags

```
final RSSItem currentMessage = new RSSItem();
    RootElement root = new RootElement(NAMESPACE, "rss");
    final List<RSSItem> messages = new ArrayList<RSSItem>();
    Element channel = root.getChild(NAMESPACE, "channel");

    //Element mainTitle = channel.getChild(NAMESPACE,"title");

    Element item = channel.getChild(NAMESPACE,ITEM);

    item.setEndElementListener(new EndElementListener() {
        public void end() {
            messages.add(currentMessage.copy());
        }
    });
    item.getChild(NAMESPACE,TITLE).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() { //this add namespace too
        public void end(String body) {
            currentMessage.setTitle(body);
        }
    });
```